# unable to compare values with httpResponse in java

Tags: java, json

i'm new to web development field and i tried to send username and password to php script and then return the result as 0 or 1.but i did not encode them when returning.
my problem is System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(entity)) prints return value as 1 when provided correct username and password but i can't compare or assign that value to variable.

```
        response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(entity));
        String s=EntityUtils.toString(entity);
```

but when i tried to compare the string value the IDE output says attempted read from closed stream

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The http response Content has been consumed when you execute "System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(entity));"
so,you will get error when you call "entity" again.

http content based on stream,you must only read once.

The following code may work:

```
response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
String s=EntityUtils.toString(entity);
System.out.println(s);
```

Comment: yes i edited my  code and it did not produce any error messages.then i entered this piece of code.                         if(s=="1")
          {
           System.out.println("passed");
           }                                                         but the required result not printing. can you please check this out.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this? :

```
"1".equals(s);
```

Comment: after a added this piece of code i tried it and used your code.it became success. thanks.                                        response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            String s=EntityUtils.toString(entity);
            System.out.println(s);